# File content into scrollable widget Kivy

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I am stuck trying to find a way to load contents from a file into a scrollable widget. I can get the content into a label (code below) But i want to make it scrollable. I am storing the contents of the file into a variable and loading the variable into label. The code below works for me, but the content of the file is too big and i can't scroll up or down. I was reading kivy documentation regarding ScrollView but i can't make it work.

```
file = open('links.txt', 'r')
linklist = (file.read())
Label = Label( text=linklist)
self.add_widget(Label)
```

Help or maybe some examples i can follow will be a great help.

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Scrollable-Label

Comment: Thanks i think i figured it out. I used kivy language to create the scroll label and used Stringproperty() to assign it to the text:

<Scrollable>:
    Label:
        text:root.text
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        Button:

py

file = open('links.txt', 'r')
        linklist = (file.read())
        text = StringProperty(linklist)